# Why is it bad to start a variable name with a dollar sign in C++/Java and similar?

Tags: java, c++, variables, naming-conventions

Why is it bad to start a variable name with a dollar sign in C++/Java and similar such as in PHP?

Edit: Are there any risks?

Comment: That's just how it was defined by the C gods, and Java took most of its syntax from C.

Comment: Also (1) there is no reason for it in C++ and Java since they aren't interpreted like PHP, Perl, and sh and (2) it is ugly.

Comment: Related to [Does C++11 allow dollar signs in identifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26301737/1708801) ... in C++ using `$` is an extension.

Comment: A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7484210/3798217) for java.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, using `$` in variables is legal but definitely a bad idea.

If you do this, there is a risk that you will accidentally use a name that collides with a name that is used by the compiler itself, or by some code generator.  The result will be unexpected compile or runtime failures that could be particularly difficult to diagnose ...

There's also a potential risk that your (mis-)use of `$` will cause problems in future versions of Java.  The Java compiler / runtime's use of `$` may change in a future, causing your abusive code to fail.

Just don't do it.  Or at least, don't do it unless you are writing a generator ... *and you know what you are getting yourself into*.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, it's non-portable.  The only characters the standard says (section `[lex.name]`) must be acceptable to begin an identifier are uppercase and lowercase letters and underscore.

Answer (score 3):

Java allows the dollar sign to begin identifiers, but recommends that it only be used for mechanically generated code. (see [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#40625))

It appears that in C++ identifiers may be able to use dollar signs as an extension, but it's not part of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

For java from [this post](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

> The convention, however, is to always
>   begin your variable names with a
>   letter, not "`$`" or "`_`". Additionally,
>   the dollar sign character, by
>   convention, is never used at all. You
>   may find some situations where
>   auto-generated names will contain the
>   dollar sign, but your variable names
>   should always avoid using it. A
>   similar convention exists for the
>   underscore character; while it's
>   technically legal to begin your
>   variable's name with "`_`", this
>   practice is discouraged.

I don't think there are any risks/side effects; it's just discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

In Java $ is used in inner class names, and probably some "synthetic" method names as well.  Basically any code that the compiler has to generate to handle inner classes will have a $ in it.  Using the $ would, at the very least be confusing because of that.  You should, generally speaking, never need to see a $ in a variables/method/class name in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [**JLS 8 3.8**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says so:

> The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

And you can really generate code that fails to compile, e.g. on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45:

```
public class Assert {
    static final boolean $assertionsDisabled = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert System.currentTimeMillis() == 0L;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `javac` generates a field `$assertionsDisabled` to implement `assert`, which conflicts with our field.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29439538/895245

Answer (score 0):

Because in both C++ and Java doing so would be a syntax error (in the case of C++) or bad style (in the case of Java). Neither of these languages need variables to be so indicated, and doing so is wrong. Starting variables with  a special character (like '$') makes things a lot easier for the language system (which is important for interpreted languages like PHP), but makes life much harder for the programmer, because they have to type in all those '$' characters. So most languages (even most interpreted languages) don't require them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$` is a legal variable name in Java.  Doesn't have to be in C++, although the implementation can allow non-standard characters to be used (it's not like C++ gives `$` any other meaning).

Comment: In Java it is perfectly legal to start your variable names with a $, but the convention is that that character is not used at all.

Comment: @Ben I know little of Java, but I've never seen any Java code that begins variables with '$' (or includes them).

Comment: In C++, an implementation is required to issue a diagnostic if an variable name contains a `$`.  (In other words, using a `$` is a diagnosable error.)

Comment: @James: Is there a rule that says this?  The latest draft only mentions the dollar sign in conjunction with numeric formatting (currency) and regular expressions (end-of-string anchor).  It appears that `$` could be an "implementation-defined character" allowed to appear in an identifier by `[lex.name]`.

Comment: @Ben: "Implementation-defined character allowed in [lex.name]" depends what standard you're talking about. My copy of C++03 allows digits, letters, underscore, and *universal-character-name*. The dollar sign doesn't fall into one of the ranges specified in Annex E. C++0x will allow other implementation-defined characters, but until then it's a grammatical error and so a C++03 standard-conforming compiler has to diagnose.

Comment: @Ben The C++03 standard clearly specifies all legal characters in an indentifier.  The "implementation-defined character" is a change, and I'm not quite sure what it is supposed to mean: could `+` be an "implementation-defined character" in this context, and `a+` thus become a single token (making an expression like `a+b` illegal)?  (Think I'm going to have to raise another DR.)

Comment: @Steve Do you have a ref for C++0x allowing other characters?

Comment: @unapersson: 2.11 [lex.name] in the current draft.

Answer (score 0):

The main reasons I can think of are here.
In Java, the inner class names are created with $ sign.
Also, the $ sign is used for env variables in most of the Oses, so it would be confusing and may intervene the system defined variables.