# What is the meaning of $ in a variable name?

Tags: java

Recently I read that the sign $ is allowed in Java variable names, but has a special meaning. Unfortunately it isn't mentioned what this special meaning is.

Therefore I ask here: What is the special meaning of $ in variable names in Java?

Here is the exact quote from

> Java: An Introduction to Problem Solving and Programming

from Walter Savitch:

> Java does allow the dollar sign symbol $ to appear in an identifier,
>   but these identifiers have a special meaning, so you should not use
>   the $ symbol in your identifiers.

Comment: Related thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167326/java-class-name-containing-dollar-sign

Comment: Citing where you read this might be nice.

Comment: AFAIK there's no special meaning, so you can use it in your variable declarations. But it violates Java Naming Conventions. Maybe he's talking about class names?

Comment: @MisterSmith I suspect the "special meaning" referred by the author is just the convention of only using it on machine-generated code. The "special meaning" is special by convention, not by semantics.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`$` is used internally by the compiler to decorate certain names. Wikipedia [gives the following example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Creating_unique_names_for_inner_and_anonymous_classes):

```
public class foo {
    class bar {
        public int x;
    }

    public void zark () {
        Object f = new Object () {
            public String toString() {
                return "hello";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Compiling this program will produce three .class files:

- `foo.class`, containing the main (outer) class `foo`
- `foo$bar.class`,
  containing the named inner class `foo.bar`
- `foo$1.class`, containing the
  anonymous inner class (local to method `foo.zark`)

All of these class names are valid (as `$` symbols are permitted in the JVM specification).

In a similar vein, `javac` uses `$` in some automatically-generated **variable names**: for example, `this$0` et al are used for the implicit `this` references from the inner classes to their outer classes.

Finally, [the JLS recommends the following](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> The `$` character should be used only in mechanically generated source
>   code or, rarely, to access preexisting names on legacy systems.

Comment: That's not really true. I can name my class Test$

Comment: The question is not asking for class names, but for variables.

Comment: What would happen if there was a class named `foo$bar`? How would its class file be distinguished from that of `bar` in `foo` in the source code?

Answer (score 39):

There is no special meaning for a `$` in a variable’s name.

While technically allowed, starting the variable name with a dollar sign goes against convention, generally used only by code-generators.

To quote the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) by Oracle:

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_". The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "_". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.