# Interpereting the output of eclipse's memory analyser

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am attempting to trace a memory leak in my game app. The program runs fine once, but if it is run and closed repeatedly then eventually it will run into some kind of not enough memory error. After much floundering with trying to install and understand eclipse's memory analyser, I finally produced the data shown in the screengrab below.

My app is based on a single Application called SD_globals like so:

```
public class SD_Globals extends Application
{
    int example_global_data = 99;
    // stuff
}
```

and five separate activities, each of which has access to a variety of global data declared in SD_Globals. One of the activities for example is SD_gameplay like so:

```
public class SD_GamePlay extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    SD_Globals gs; // gs stands for global state

    gs = ((SD_Globals)getApplicationContext());

    // now I can access global variable using code like this:
    int x = gs.example_global_data;
}
```

Looking at the data in the screengrab, the repeated instances of GamePlay looks odd. My guess is that perhaps somehow new activities are being created afresh each time the activity executes without being garbage collected (am I right?)... And if so, what kind of thing could cause that?

**EDIT:** If I'm completely off track about my interpretation, is there anything *else* that looks suspicious in the image?

[image]

Comment: Have you watched this Google IO video before? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk I believe it explains in detail how to use the memory analyzer tool. I don't recall exactly where to click, but I believe there's a way for each object there to see which object is holding a reference to it, thus not letting it be collected. Should be described in detail in the video.

Answer (score 1):

`SD_GamePlay$1`, `SD_GamePlay$2` and others aren't instances of `SD_GamePlay` class. It is just anonymous inner classes in `SD_GamePlay` class. `SD_GamePlay$MicksPanelThing` and `SD_GamePlay$MicksThreadThing` are non-anonymous inner classes in `SD_GamePlay` class.

Explanation of $ in name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484241/436938