# Is there any specific reason behind using $ with variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know it's a silly question but I am a bit confused with this. For example, if I have an input with an ID: `rad1`, is there any difference between below lines of code?

```
var $a = $('#rad1')
```

or

```
var a = $('#rad1')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a JavaScript variable start with a dollar sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**No there is no real difference.**

It's just a convention that helps you remember that `a` isn't the DOM element but it's a jQuery object.

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
a.innerHTML  //fine

var $a = $('#a');
$a.html()   // fine
```

Ohhh, and by the way, neither `a` or `$a` are good variable names ... you should use meaningful variable names not abc characters.

---

Read the [jQuery info tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) on this very same site:

**Variable Naming Conventions**

jQuery wrapped variables are usually named starting with '$' to distinguish them from standard JavaScript objects.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: I come from java background.. and this answer really enlightened my day.I just know that in JS I can use $ in var name..

Comment: Funny thing is, you can [use $ in Java variables as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name).

Answer (score 5):

It's only for showing that it's a Jquery variable.

Declaring `$a` you're showing that your variable is for JQuery objects, it's just a notation. So the most readable thing will be to declare Jquery variable with $ notation

```
var $obj=$("#obj");
```

And DOM element without $ notation

```
var obj = document.getElementById("obj");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference. It's just a coding convention to help identify that the variable represents a jquery wrapped object.

Answer (score 1):

No difference its just coding convention , [check this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1778-Using-Variable-In-jQuery-Code-Is-Just-Hungarian-Notation.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think this scenario should illustrate the reason for remembering(off course, assigning '$' ) jquery and simple javascript variables:

```
<form id='myform' >
  <input id="name" type="text" value="Peter" />
</form>

 <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
      var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var $name = $('#name');

  console.log(name.value);   // javascript's properties are available 
       console.log($name.value);  //it is undefined  (worth of notice)

  console.log(name.val());   // error!  name.val is not a function !  (jquery function will not be available)
  console.log($name.val());    // jquery functions are available

});

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A composition also works fine:

You can also do something like this to show a `<div>`:

```
function getCompTable(divId){
  var $d = $('#' + divId);
  $d.show();
}
```

**USAGE**

```
getCompTable('compListDiv'); // compListDiv - is a div id=""
```

Yosi Lev