# disable form post enter when pressed

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, autocomplete

Hello I have a autocomplete event work with press enter. But it's in a form so how disable the press enter event for the form method?

Here my code

```
<tr>
    <td>    
    <form action = 'insert.php' method="post" onsubmit="return false;" >
    <p>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="client7" class = "client" size="12" id ="client7" readonly />
    </td>
    <td>
                        <!-- dꣵt section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->                    
    <label title="Select your state"> 
    <select title="Select your state" id="state" name="state">
    <?php
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo ' <option title="';
        echo $row['tacName'];
        echo '">';
        echo $row['tacId'];
        echo '</option>'."\n";
        $task = array();
    }
    ?>
</select>
</label>
<!-- Fin section cobobox tache avec tool tip -->    
</td>   
<td>
    <span id="calculTemps6">
    <input  id="input7" class= "temps"  type="number"  size="2" min="0" max="24" value="0"></br>
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
<input type="text" id="result" readonly="readonly" name="total" />
<input type="submit"  value="Terminé" id="end" />
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />

</p>
</form>
</td>
</td>
```

Comment: This has been answered numerous times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313032/stop-enter-return-key-submitting-a-form

Comment: Can you please format your code..

Comment: Sidenote: Using jQuery is only effective if JS is enabled.

Comment: both won't work for my case

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to disable it

```
base.keypress(function(e) {
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
if(code == 13)
    return false;
});
```

Comment: how do I link it to my form post?

Comment: Just include it in the head of the page as you would with javascript. http://jquery.com/

Comment: won't work and yes the script is in the top of my page witch my other function

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library?

Comment: yes   `code<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`