# Semantic UI Dropdown submits form on select option

Tags: semantic-ui, dropdown, multiple-select

I have a big problem with the Semantic UI dropdown extension. I've configured multiple search dropdown with ajax back-end. And when user tries to add new item, form is submitting.

**My dropdown configuration**:

```
    $(e).dropdown({
        allowAdditions: true,
        saveRemoteData: false,
        action: 'combo',
        match: 'text',
        apiSettings: {
          url: data('api')
        }
    })
```

**Goal**: when I add new item to multiple select, form is not submitting.

Comment: are you using "enter" key inside select?

Comment: Goal of field is possibility to select tags from existing list or create new.
And when I add nonexistance tag and press ENTER - form submits.

Comment: I do not know what's the actual solution to this, but you can probably add key handler for the div that sits around dropdown and execute stopPropagation() on the event. Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313032/stop-enter-return-key-submitting-a-form

Comment: the trick is to place the handler on the element that contains only the dropdown form.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Just stumbled across the same issue and before I spend the time I thought I'd ask!

Comment: Looks like this might be a bug since Semantic has specific handling for stopping this from happening, it just seems to not work.

Comment: @NilsLuxton: in case you haven't found a solution yet, see my answer below (add the `keys.delimiter` key in your dropdown declaration).

Comment: @clairity thanks - I submitted a PR to fix the issue but no movement in a few weeks; I think Semantic is going through a slow phase...!

Answer (score 2):

i found a solution to this issue [here (Semantic-UI issue #4763)](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4763). just add the `keys.delimiter` key in your dropdown declaration:

```
$(e).dropdown({
  allowAdditions: true,
  saveRemoteData: false,
  action: 'combo',
  match: 'text',
  apiSettings: {
    url: data('api')
  },
  keys: {
    delimiter: 13
  }
});
```