# The preferred way of creating a new element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, createelement, jquery-append

I've got 2 ways I can create a `<div>` using `jQuery`.

Either:

```
var div = $("<div></div>");
$("#box").append(div);
```

Or:

```
$("#box").append("<div></div>");
```

What are the drawbacks of using second way other than re-usability?

Comment: It's just matter of reusability. Your call.

Comment: @gdoron by reusability I mean : if you have an element inside a variable, than you can re-call that var wherever you need, just like in your example.

Comment: Why `.html`, but not `.append` in 2nd case?

Comment: @Engineer - Sorry, that was mistake here. I corrected that.

Comment: I thought the latter method was faster in terms of speed execution but the first one seems (10% ~ 40%) faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-string-vs-append-jquery-reference

Comment: @F.Calderan. You read it wrong, **"operations per second (higher is better)"**. And should test it with more complex elements than a blank div.

Comment: to me the first one makes 8000 ops/sec, the second 4900 ops/sec => the first is faster. anyway I will try to add more markup :)

Comment: @F.Calderan. [check this](http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-string-vs-append-jquery-reference/2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a div element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867916/creating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Comment: The first one is a low level programmatic builder approach (fast).
The second can be complex html as string which is parsed (expensive).

Answer (score 383, accepted):

The first option gives you more flexibilty:

```
var $div = $("<div>", {id: "foo", "class": "a"});
$div.click(function(){ /* ... */ });
$("#box").append($div);
```

And of course `.html('*')` overrides the content while `.append('*')` doesn't, but I guess, this wasn't your question.

Another good practice is prefixing your jQuery variables with `$`:
[Is there any specific reason behind using $ with variable in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10204606/601179)

Placing quotes around the `"class"` property name will make it more compatible with less flexible browsers.

Comment: Also a good practice to start jQuery collection names with a "`$`", in my opinion.  Just noting that what you've done does not require `$div`: `$("<div>", {id: 'foo', class: 'a', click: function () {}}).appendTo("#box");`

Comment: Are those dollar signs necessary or a typo? `$div`. I haven't seen that syntax before, but I'm new to Jquery.

Comment: I always use the $ is the variable is a jquery object, $_ if it is a jQuery collection, and _var if it is a counter. The var for regular variables.

Comment: where is the documentation for this way of creating element? `$("<div>", {id: "foo", class: "a"});`. I want to know if there are other options for it

Comment: @gdoron please, take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413044/which-is-the-correct-or-better-way-to-create-a-new-element-with-jquery

Comment: why is the id key without quotes whereas the class key requires quotes

Comment: @codemonkey `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript while `id` is not. Hence the difference. See http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Answer (score 88):

I personally think that it's more important for the code to be readable and editable than performant. Whichever one you find easier to look at and it should be the one you choose for above factors. 
You can write it as:

```
$('#box').append(
  $('<div/>')
    .attr("id", "newDiv1")
    .addClass("newDiv purple bloated")
    .append("<span/>")
      .text("hello world")
);
```

And your first Method as:

```
// create an element with an object literal, defining properties
var $e = $("<div>", {id: "newDiv1", name: 'test', class: "aClass"});
$e.click(function(){ /* ... */ });
// add the element to the body
$("#box").append($e);
```

**But as far as readability goes; [the jQuery approach is my favorite](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). Follow this [Helpful jQuery Tricks, Notes, and Best Practices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/)**

Comment: Thanks for that link to the [jQuery reference on creating new HTML elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). SO hard to google for that.

Comment: Better do it like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43719563/383904

Answer (score 29):

Much more expressive way,

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    "id": 'foo',
    "name": 'mainDiv',
    "class": 'wrapper',
    "click": function() {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass("test");
    }}).appendTo('selector');
```

Reference: [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Be sure to read the docs thoroughly, as this notation has certain consequences that won't be immediately obvious to the person inspecting the code.

> The name `"class"` must be quoted in the object since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and `"className"` cannot be used since it refers to the DOM property, not the attribute.
> While the second argument is convenient, its flexibility can lead to unintended consequences (e.g. `$( "<input>", {size: "4"} )` calling the `.size()` method instead of setting the `size` attribute).

Comment: `class` should be in quotes, according to the docs (via Docs link above): "The name "class" must be quoted in the object since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it refers to the DOM property, not the attribute."

Answer (score 7):

According to the [jQuery official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument)

To create a HTML element, `$("<div/>")` or `$("<div></div>")` is preferred.

Then you can use either `appendTo`, `append`, `before`, `after` and etc,. to insert the new element to the DOM.

PS: jQuery Version 1.11.x

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation for [3.4](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), It is preferred to use attributes with `attr()` method.

```js
$('<div></div>').attr(
  {
    id: 'some dynanmic|static id',
    "class": 'some dynanmic|static class'
  }
).click(function() {
  $( "span", this ).addClass( "bar" ); // example from the docs
});
```

Comment: I added quotes.  If you don't put `class` in quotes, this will silently fail and may result in insanity.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the first option, where you actually build elements using jQuery. the second approach simply sets the innerHTML property of the element to a string, which happens to be HTML, and is more error prone and less flexible.

Comment: @Ash with the second approach, you may mistakenly wipe out all of the other children of the container you are modifying: http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/RBXq5/1/

Answer (score 0):

If `#box` is empty, nothing, but if it's not these do very different things.  The former will add a `div` as the last child node of `#box`.  The latter completely replaces the contents of `#box` with a single empty `div`, text and all.

Comment: Oh .. I mean't to use append here ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to create a div element in the following way:

```
var my_div = document.createElement('div');
```

add class

```
my_div.classList.add('col-10');
```

also can perform `append()` and `appendChild()`