# how to inject controls using javascript at runtime for a web page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am planning to inject three buttons in the web pages I have been given(Development is done and only URL'S are shared) and upon clicking on each one of those buttons , I need to do certain actions.

Can anyone share how I can do this using JavaScript.Any link which can help me start with creating buttons, and code behind for clicks on buttons and how do I load that JavaScript in browser etc.

Comment: Why don't you use any search engine as google???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add elements at runtime **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

Suppose you have,

```
<div id="container"> <div>
```

And you have to inject buttons into this.

```
$('#container').append('<input type="button" id="b1" value="Button1" /><input type="button" id="b2" value="Button2" /><input type="button" id="b3" value="Button3" />');
```

Where, #container is a selector for `<div>` with ID - container.

For click(),

```
$('#b1').click(function(){
    //do your action
}
```

Don't forget to add reference to **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)**

**[Sample Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/7ReWy/)**

Comment: Yup, pretty much what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

[Best way of creating a new element in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619445/best-way-of-creating-a-new-element-in-jquery)

Once created, you can use [Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach the functionality you need for each button.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the [jquery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

```
$('#TheContainingElement').append('<input type="button" id="MyButtonID" value="Click Me" />');
```

Once you've created it you can wire the click events

```
$('#MyButtonID').click(function(){
  // do something
});
```