# One of Jquery 's select function

Tags: jquery, html

I found a `Jquery`'s select function,

but I have confuse in this syntax , I dont know what it effect.

Does anyone can help me for explain this syntax do or what it effect ?

```
$("<table>",{ id: "tableName"  }))
```

This syntax are so weird to me.

`Jquery` selector can select element without `ID` or `class` , just a html element ? and what does `{ }` mean in that selector ?

In confused... and didn't find any tutorial about that...

Comment: Here's the documentation for that jQuery example: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I linked the paragraph just above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a select statement.

It creates a table object with the ID of tableName -

Here is the API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

and here is a post on preferred usage

[The preferred way of creating a new element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619445/the-prefered-way-of-creating-a-new-element-with-jquery) -

That said, when you do

```
var $table = $("<table>",{ id: "tableName"  }));
```

the variable $table will contain the jQuery object of the created table for further manipulation such as appending a `thead` and `tbody` with content

Comment: Thank you , you clarify the confusion