# Selecting a div corresponding to TD on click w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table. When I click on(within) a TD I need to show a hidden div that contains several more divs inside. Each div inside that hidden container has a text value. I need to select the one which value corresponds to the clicked TD.

**JS**

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
    $("#hiddenDiv").hide().fadeIn(200);

    if ($(this).text() == $("#hiddenDiv div").text()) {
         //  HOW DO I SELECT THAT DIV? 
         // matched div .css("color", "red");  
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTbl">
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td class="clickme">Left</td>  
</tr>
</table>

<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
  <div>Straight</div>
  <div>Left</div>
  <div>Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[demo jsBIn](http://jsbin.com/uvukaz/2/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){

    var thisText = $(this).text();
    var $targetEl =  $('#hiddenDiv > div:contains('+thisText+')');

    if( $targetEl.length > 0 ){  // if exists
          $("#hiddenDiv").hide().fadeIn(200);
         $targetEl.css({color:'red'});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use *:contains* to select the correct one:

```
$("#hiddenDiv div:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")")
```

Comment: contains is not like the `==` that was used in the question.

Comment: Don't think there should be a space between `div` and the `:contains()`.

Comment: @gdoron I think it's more than sufficient for the scope of the problem, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".clickme").click(function() {
    $("#hiddenDiv").hide().fadeIn(200);
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#hiddenDiv div").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == $this.text();
    }).css("color", "red").show();
});​
```

Comment: @Sagiv. Read the answer again... you're wrong! `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: u right, i didn't notice. but it's good practice to avoid $this syntaks since it's confusing specially if you compare it to $(this)

Comment: @Sagiv. `$this` is a very common use. Read this: 
[Is there any specific reason behind using $ with variable in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10204606/601179)

Comment: it's all depends on the context. i think that line like '$(this).text() == $this.text();' can be right, but confusing and should be rewrite.