# How to check checkbox in each loop

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, jquery

Consider a simple each loop to inspect checked checkboxes:

```
$(':checkbox').filter(':checked').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
});
```

This code works for checkboxes checked in the original HTML code as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" checked="checked" />
```

How to make this jQuery code to work live, to perform the `filter` process every time a new box is checked or a checked is removed. I want to run the each loop upon any change in the checkbox (checked or unchecked) to return the updated values of currently checked ones.

**NOTE:** This is a simplified code to express the issue. The intention is not to record the `name`, but processing checked values in the `each` loop.

Comment: Nobody follows the "each" tag. EDIT: WAIT, there are two guys following it. My bad.

Comment: @Aerovistae why not, each loop is quite useful ;)

Comment: @Aerovistae. We (jquery users) have that `jquery-each` tag... EDITED. anyway the tags are not **just** for the followers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `click`:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').filter(':checked').each(function() {
        var name = this.value;
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- You can avoid query the DOM so many times.
- `:checkbox` is a very slow selector, because it's not a css selector but a jQuery extension.
- Don't use jQuery to get `this` value.

You can improve your code like that:

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    var name = this.value;
});
```

**Reading resources:**

- [The cost of `$(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179)
- [Why we prefix our variables with $ in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10204606/601179)

Comment: I really like the way you answer, I learned a lot. Don't worry about `name`, it is a long process with checked values. It is very simplified code to discuss the issue. I deeply appreciate your concern about performance, what most of people simply ignore :) I wish I could give +10 for this!

Comment: @Ali. I'm glad I could help. I added reading resources to the answers. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to bind your loop to the [`change` event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) for the checkboxes.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    $(':checkbox').filter(':checked').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: it works perfectly, but has one problem. It will start to work upon first change. I mean it will not work for default checked values (those checked in the original html code).

Comment: @Ali. Then use `click` instead. I [posted it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10670053/601179)...

Comment: @Ali, just run the inner loop once the page is loaded, either before or after you bind it. Better yet, put the inner loop in a separate function so that you'd just call it once when the page is loaded, and bind it to the event.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're performing a loop, I'm assuming there can be many checked boxes. I'm a little confused why you would be overwriting the `name` variable each time though, leaving you only with the value of the last checkbox in the end. Instead, I'm providing an array which we push all checked values onto:

```
// Declare a names variable for storing values
var names;

// Any time a checkbox changes on our form
$("form").on("change", ":checkbox", function(e){
  // Empty the names array
  names = [];
  // Get all checked checkboxes from our form and add their value to our array
  $(":checkbox:checked", e.delegateTarget).each(function(){
    names.push( $(this).val() ); 
  });
}).find("input:checkbox").trigger("change");

// Method of revealing what we currently have checked
$("#reveal").on("click", function(){
  alert( names.join(", ") );
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uyecux/2/edit

Comment: As I added to a NOTE, `name` was a simplified example to complete the loop. The actual process is quite long. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, you could use `.map` instead of pushing elements to array. Do you want me to give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event handler.  In jQuery, this might look like this:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  // Execute your code here.
});
```

See the jQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more details on event handling in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]')  
$checkboxes.click(function (){  
    $(':checkbox').filter(':checked').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Try using above function.