# Having difficulty understanding a Java 8 Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

```
private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true); // allows app to exit if tasks are running
    return t ;
});
```

I understand the idea behind an executor but, the paramater `r` is confusing me. I used:

```
 final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        System.out.println("Class of r: " + r.getClass()+ ". r to string: " + r.toString());
        System.out.println("Class of t: " + t.getClass() +". Name of t: "+ t.getName());
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });
```

to dig deeper and the result is:

```
Class of r: class java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker. r to string: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1dc3963[State = -1, empty queue]
Class of t: class java.lang.Thread. Name of t: Thread-3
```

`r` is being passed as a parameter to the `Thread` object constructor.

1. How is the simple letter `r` indicating that the object being passed is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`?
2. How is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`passable as a parameter if it does not implement `Runnable` as required by the by `Thread's` constructor?

If someone could provide me with a non-lambda version of the code as well, it would be of great benefit to my understanding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`newSingleThreadExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-) takes a ThreadFactory as an argument. [`ThreadFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) defines a single method `newThread` that takes a Runnable as an argument and returns a Thread.

The lambda may make more sense to you if we specify the type of `r` explicitly:

```
(Runnable r) -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    return t;
}
```

Now it is more obvious this is a definition for the body of `newThread`.

Except that since the lambda is immediately passed as an argument to a method that accepts a ThreadFactory, the compiler is able to infer that the type of `r` must be Runnable. Therefore it can be omitted.

Without the lambda, this code translates to the following anonymous class definition and instantiation:

```
private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
    new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }
    }
);
```

> How is the simple letter `r` indicating that the object being passed is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

The type of `r` is Runnable because the target type of the lambda expression defines its single method that way.

The object you are seeing passed is actually a `ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker` which is a private inner class of ThreadPoolExecutor that implements Runnable.

> How is a `ThreadPoolExecutor` passable as a parameter if it does not implement `Runnable` as required by the by `Thread`'s constructor?

See above (`r` is a Runnable).

Comment: Thanks, Radiodef. I fully understand the code now. Where can I learn more about `outerclass$innerclass` type notations - the Java Language Specification?

Comment: I'm glad to explain it. Also there is not a whole lot more to learn about the `$`. When you refer to a nested or inner class in the code you use `Outer.Inner` but typically it is actually compiled to a class called `Outer$Inner`. The `$` is a valid character for all identifiers but it is usually considered reserved for internal mechanisms. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7484210/2891664

Comment: You may see dollar signs at other classes too, e.g. when you see a class name like `ClassContainingLambda$$Lambda$1`, it’s not an inner class…