# What does '$' means in "int $value" in android or java?

Tags: java, android

In the source, there are some '$'.
I don't know about these '$' means. Where does these '$' come from? Java, or android?

```
public static synchronized PreferenceUtil instance(Context $context) {
  if (_instance == null)
     _instance = new PreferenceUtil($context);
  return _instance;
}
```

It is also difficult to find the answer of interest and search for $. Could you anyone help?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7484210/1741542

Comment: $ is generally use for nested class naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means someone has a background in another language and is naming his variables according to its preferences (perhaps marking method parameters with a `$` prefix).

Even though it's syntactically correct, it makes code harder to read for other Java developers, since Java has its own recommended styles.