# Is it proper way to set names of some variables using $ char?

Tags: java, variables, sonarqube

While I was going through one project I found some strange variables names. Sonarqube gaves me Code Smell statements about these variables.

For example `protected String value$editedby$java$lang$String;`

And message from Sonarqube:

```
Rename this field "value$editedby$java$lang$String" to match the regular expression '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
```

So is it proper way to use `$` in variables names?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name

Comment: You might wanna ask this question on Code Review network rather than StackOverflow...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7484245/348975](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7484245/348975) explains why you should not use `$`.  It is largely bullshit in my opinion - if you are not supposed to use `$` why is it an allowed character.  On the other hand there is no strong compelling reason to use `$` and it is commonly accepted BS - so I follow along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against it, [JLS-3.8. Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says (in part)

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters `A`-`Z` (`\u0041`-`\u005a`), and `a`-`z` (`\u0061`-`\u007a`), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (`_`, or `\u005f`) and dollar sign (`$`, or `\u0024`). **The `$` sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.**

Answer (score 1):

While it's technically legal to use the `$` character in variable names, Java's coding standard discourages this. The usual convention for variables is lowerCaseCamelCase. So, in your case:

```
protected String valueEditedByJavaLangString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Camel case is recommended with a lowercase first letter. Variable names should not start with underscore `_` or dollar sign `$` characters, even though both are allowed.

I would add that the `$` character is traditionally used by the compiler in the name of generated class file for inner class.