# Jar isn't able to load folder containing class files

Tags: java, exception, classpath, jython, executable-jar

I'm making a Maven project with Jython. In Eclipse it runs fine, **but when I run the exported `jar` it trows an exception.**

This are my directories inside `src/main/resources`:

```
src/main/resources:
    mylib
        file_one.py
        file_two.py
    pylib
        sys.py
        sys$py.class
        os.py
        os$py.class
        ...
```

I've been trying to load my folder `pylib` containing class files in `src/main/resources` with this snippet of code:

```
public class MyClass {

    // ...

    public static void init() {
        // ...
        ClassLoader classLoader = Prompt.class.getClassLoader();
        addToPath(path, classLoader.getResource("mylib").getPath());
        System.out.println("Found mylib");
        addToPath(path, classLoader.getResource("pylib").getPath());
        System.out.println("Found pylib");
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

While exporting to jar **I got this error**:

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  Problem writing project/src/main/resources/.DS_Store to JAR: duplicate entry: .DS_Store
  duplicate entry: .DS_Store
```

I tested it multiple times, but the jar only included the folder `mylib` that didn't contain class files. If I included `pylib` I got this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at *project*.Prompt.init(Prompt.java:53)
    at *project*.Prompt.start(Prompt.java:76)
    at *project*.Main.main(Main.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

> Note:
>   I replaced my group id with `*package*` to hide the identity of my project.

**Does anyone know how to load the class files?**

> Edit:
>
> - Corrected code by adding semicolons.
> - Added `println` expression to make clear where the executed jar failed.
> - Added path information.
> - Changed class and project name.
> - Added export error.
> - Extended runtime error

Comment: Are you trying to load python files in java?

Comment: Yes I am, using Jython

Comment: check if `pylib` is in the JAR file (jar -tvf project.jar)

Comment: Yes there is: `0 Thu Jun 01 16:57:38 CEST 2017 pylib/`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger If you look at the dollar sign in `sys$py.class`, maybe --> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name) has to do something with my problem. If somebody knows why and how to fix it, *please answer.*

Comment: in the JAR file? it's just strange that it apparently is not finding the `pylib` as resource... at least I think it is that line that is throwing the exception. maybe it helps if you print out the result of `classLoader.getResource("pylib")` and `classLoader.getResource("pylib").getPath()`. Also unconventional to have .class files in the `src/` tree... could be the problem if Prompt.class is under a different folder/tree.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I extended the exception above. I tried to put the `pylib` folder at the root of the project but that didn't work either. I also tried to replace the `$`s by `_`s, but that also didn't work.

Comment: why root? Is your Prompt.class behind loaded from there? Anyway I will stop guessing and wait for ""you print out the result of classLoader.getResource("pylib") and classLoader.getResource("pylib").getPath()""

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I forgot to answer that. Direct answer: It throws an `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: the first one - `classLoader.getResource("pylib")`?? hmm, would mean that the Prompt.class has no ClassLoader [:-0  (instead of a direct answer, a detailed one would be better)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Though `classLoader.getResource("mylib")` the directory without classes, didn't throw an Exception.

Comment: I suspect that getting a directory as resource from a JAR file will not work (always). Try with `classLoader.getResource("pylib/sys$py.class")...` or with any other file in that directory

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It still works in eclipse, but doesn't in the executed jar.

Comment: see my answer, comments are to hard to format...

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be how the JAR file was created or what is in it.

I just did a mostly minimal complete sample. Works in Eclipse, Windows command prompt, Git Bash and SUSE Linux!

Directory structure:

```
./bin
./bin/classes
./bin/classes/project
./bin/classes/project/Prompt.class
./bin/classes/pylib
./bin/classes/pylib/file.txt
./py.jar
./py.jardesc
./src
./src/java
./src/java/project
./src/java/project/Prompt.java
./src/java/pylib
./src/java/pylib/file.txt
```

Prompt.java:

```
package project;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Prompt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassLoader cl = Prompt.class.getClassLoader();
        URL url;
        url = cl.getResource("pylib");
        System.out.println(url);

        url = cl.getResource("pylib/file.txt");
        System.out.println(url);
        try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) ch);
            }
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

file.txt (for testing):

```
Just a test
```

JAR created by Eclipses JAR Export Wizard with following settings:

1. selecting resources to export: "project" **and "pylib"** directories
2. activating "Export generated class files and resources
3. **selecting option "Add directory entries"**
4. choosing "Generate the manifest file"
5. entering "project.Prompt" as Main class

The content of the JAR is (first line is prompt and the command to generate that listing):

```
$ jar -tvf py.jar
    53 Fri Jun 02 07:42:02 UTC 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Jun 02 07:34:10 UTC 2017 pylib/
    11 Fri Jun 02 07:34:20 UTC 2017 pylib/file.txt
     0 Fri Jun 02 07:36:34 UTC 2017 project/
  1480 Fri Jun 02 07:41:54 UTC 2017 project/Prompt.class
```

Executed by:

1. Eclipse: Run as > Java Application
2. DOS/Command prompt: java -jar py.jar
3. DOS/Command prompt: java -cp py.jar project.Prompt
4. Git Bash: java -jar py.jar
5. Git Bash: java -cp py.jar project.Prompt
6. SUSE Linux, different computer, empty folder: java -jar py.jar
7. SUSE Linux, different computer, empty folder: java -cp py.jar project.Prompt

It generates almost the same output for all the above cases, just the path is different:

> Eclipse:
>
> ```
> file:/C:/DEVELOP/ECLIPSE/test/bin/classes/pylib
> file:/C:/DEVELOP/ECLIPSE/test/bin/classes/pylib/file.txt
> Just a test
> ```
>
> DOS prompt, Git Bash:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/C:/DEVELOP/ECLIPSE/test/py.jar!/pylib
> jar:file:/C:/DEVELOP/ECLIPSE/test/py.jar!/pylib/file.txt
> Just a test
> ```
>
> SUSE Linux:
>
> ```
> jar:file:/home/user/pytest/py.jar!/pylib
> jar:file:/home/user/pytest/py.jar!/pylib/file.txt
> Just a test
> ```

Compiled and executed with Java 8 on Windows; executed with Java 9 on SUSE Linux.

Comment: 'file.txt' is used just for testing access to a file (and I know I could/should use a buffer to read it...)

Comment: Your settings almost worked by making one little change: **selecting option "Export all output folders for checked projects"**! The only thing that's now happening is that my `jython-2.7.0.jar` can't find the resources from the path. I'll be trying to change the `jython-2.7.0.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to detect the `project/resources` folder.