# Enable assert in a maven built project

Tags: java, maven, assert

I have a java program that is built using Maven and I need to enable the `assert` keyword. Ideally, I'd want to enable assertions in the maven build command.

Comment: [By default, Surefire enables JVM assertions for the execution of your test cases](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#enableAssertions)

Comment: The problem is I need the assertions in my main program, not in my test cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maven compiles and builds the java code. Assertion errors come when you are actually running java code so with maven you can't do it this way

unless you are using maven plugin to launch java code, you would have to supply  `-ea` to jvm

**`exec:java`**

Pass `-ea` to [commandline argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/what-does-the-java-assert-keyword-do-and-when-should-it-be-used)

**Surefire**

if you meant for test execution then configure sure-fire plugin to pass `-ea` to jvm

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: The surefire plugin enables assertions by default: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#enableAssertions so there is no need to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

The only things that worked for me was

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-ea"
```

Comment: When running java from mvn via exec:java this solution works to enable assertions.

Comment: This is the only correct answer really fitting the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *build* application with assertions enabled since they are enabled at runtime depending on whetevery or not you pass `-ea` argument to JVM. Here is configuration of maven exec plugin that enables assertions when running a program:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-ea</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument> <classpath />
                    <argument>io.mc.validationdemo.App</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```