# How to see test failed in mvn

Tags: java, maven

I have one single simple test

```
public class SimpleCheck {
    @Test
    public void check(){
        assertTrue(1 < 0);
    }
}
```

I run `mvn test` and see following message.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ check-check ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.024 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-10T23:25:13+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you noticed this test will fails, however i don't see any failures at least.
I have clean pom.xml with just one junit dependency.

How to see failures?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution - i should simply name it with *Test prefix. My test was Check, and now it is CheckTest.

Comment: looks like you don't have assertion enabled while running tests [you need to enable them][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966620/enable-assert-in-a-maven-built-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you don't have assertion enabled while running tests [you need to enable them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966620/enable-assert-in-a-maven-built-project)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help for me. Now i have a little bigger stacktrace of mvn test

Comment: could you post that bigger stacktrace

Comment: I had a name of test Check, but now i've got CheckTest and it is working with your assertion proposal