# Assertion Error issue

Tags: java, exception, ocpjp

I have posted this elsewhere, no solution yet, so posting it here as well. The below mentioned code is not throwing an assertion error as I expected it to since num is less than 5. Hope someone can advise. Thank you.

```
public class Wrong {  
public static void main(String[] args) {      
    Wrong wrong = new Wrong();            
    wrong.methodE(3);                 
    }     
    //AssertionError  
    void methodE(int num)  
    {  
        assert(num>5);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Answers below covered how to fix your particular issue but for more on `assert` in Java check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/assertion-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to [enable assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable).

Run the jvm with the `-ea` argument.

```
java -ea ...
```

you should also consider to provide an assertion error message, e.g.

```
assert num > 5 : "arg num must be greater than 5";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse go to `Run--> Run Configuration --> VM Argument ---> Type -ea.`

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response. Vinayak, I am using eclipse and your solution works. Thanks.