# Where is javax.annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Ok, so this is probably a NooB question (I'm more of a C++ guy), but I'm lost in the java woods and its frameworks forests...

I'm trying to look into eclipse RCP development. For that I'm following this well-known tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html

At step 15 I need to add the following dependency packages to import in my bundle.
javax.annotation
javax.injection

The problem is that I cannot select these (they are not in the selection list)
I do have javax.el javax.servlet.* and javax.xml.*

Looking at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html
suggests that this should be part of the standard java.

What obvious mistake am I missing?

Answer (score 28):

The dependency including version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

See: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api

Or for the newer `jakarta.annotation`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

See: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api

The Java Common Annotations Module java.xml.ws.annotation was deprecated in Java version 9 and was removed in java version 11. If this leads to a problem you could try to add javax.annotation.

The Javadocs for Java 8 can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/package-summary.html

Comment: I've tried to import the "guava" library from here: https://github.com/google/guava , but I keep getting errors about the "javax.annotation*" missing, even though I've set the compiler to be of version 8 of Java. How come it's still missing? Can you please help on that?

Answer (score 6):

Your comment indicates this is for Guava, so you want [the JSR305 library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305), which extends the `javax` package.

*2020 Update*: Note that [this library breaks the Oracle licensing agreement](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2960) and Guava has since moved to [checkerframework's Nullable annotation](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/Nullable.html).

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but for Java 8, I had to add the two following Maven dependencies in order to get javax.annotation.concurrent.ThreadSafe to work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java version >= 6, you should not need to add them explicitly.
They are part of the JDK. Just try to skip adding them, maybe
the list of instructions is outdated.

Before Java 6, you would have needed to add this jar, I think: **jsr250-api-1.0.jar**.

http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/

http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/

Answer (score 2):

Javax annotations include in this dependency. This is latest version at the moment.

For maven

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For gradle

```
compile('com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for `nullable` annotations, [JSpecify](https://jspecify.dev/) is the modern way to go.

They have [`@Nullable`](https://jspecify.dev/docs/user-guide#nullable)

```java
static void print(@Nullable String x) {
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(x));
}
```

More interestingly, they have [`@NullMarked`](https://jspecify.dev/docs/user-guide#nullmarked), which states that the whole thing is checked for nullness. If there is no `@Nullable` marking, the assurance is that there is no `null` appearing.

```java
@NullMarked
public class Strings {
  public static String nullToEmpty(@Nullable String x) {
    return (x == null) ? "" : x;
  }

  public static int spaceIndex(String x) {
    return x.indexOf(' ');
  }
}
```