# assert(false) vs RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception, assert, assertion

I'm reading the source of [XWalkUIClientInternal](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/blob/master/runtime/android/core_internal/src/org/xwalk/core/internal/XWalkUIClientInternal.java) and I ran into the following code:

```
    switch(type) {
        case JAVASCRIPT_ALERT:
            return onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        case JAVASCRIPT_CONFIRM:
            return onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        case JAVASCRIPT_PROMPT:
            return onJsPrompt(view, url, message, defaultValue, result);
        case JAVASCRIPT_BEFOREUNLOAD:
            // Reuse onJsConfirm to show the dialog.
            return onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        default:
            break;
    }
    assert(false);
    return false;
```

I've never really seen this technique nor really thought about it before, but I guess this essentially means "this is unreachable code and should not happen ever", and crash the app no matter what. Although technically you can do that with a Throwable, as long as it's not caught.

So my question is, which one is better and why, `assert(false)` or throwing a `RuntimeException`, or maybe an `Error`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The biggest difference between

```
assert false;
```

(The parenthesis are not needed, `assert` is not a function but a statement.) and

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

is that the assertion can be disabled.  Actually, it *is* disabled by default unless the JVM is started with the `-ea` (“enable assertions”) flag.  If assertions are enabled, `assert false` will unconditionally throw an [`AssertionError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) which derives from `Error`.  But since assertions can be disabled, there are two problems,

- the error might go undetected and
- control flow analysis requires a dummy `return` statement after the `assert` (which is mostly clutter).

Therefore, in the above case, I'd certainly go with an explicit (and more concise)

```
throw new AssertionError("invalid type " + type);
```

instead of an `assert` followed by a dummy `return`.

As mentioned in the comments, this is assuming that `type` is an internal parameter and an invalid value indicates a bug in the logic itself.  If it is an input parameter, it should be validated according to the usual rules and an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) be thrown if validation fails.

Comment: And if you wanted to throw something, would you throw a `RuntimeException` so that not even `catch(Exception e)` would catch it, or a subclass of `Error`?

Comment: You can throw an `AssertionError`, that's probably most appropriate.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that does seem like the best approach. It's more informative than just `Assertion failed: false`, and isn't caught by a mere `catch(Exception e)` branch.

Comment: Note that you can also add a custom error message to an `assert`ion if you like.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2758262/1392132) for a short example.

Comment: I disagree: I would rather use `IllegalStateException` is `type` is invalid rather than `AssertionError`. Any `Error` shouldn't be unless a serious condition occurred. Besides, the Javadoc states that `AssertionError`: `Thrown to indicate that an assertion has failed.`. It's **specific** to `assert`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi If `type` is an input parameter, then an `IllegalArgumentException` is appropriate.  But I was assuming that this is some internal code where an invalid value of `type` indicates a bug in the logic itself, not a wrong usage by the client.

Comment: I did not mention `IllegalArgumentException` but of `IllegalStateException`. Internally, `type` has a state, hence why I used it.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I know, but I think that an `IllegalStateException` should only be used if it's the client's fault that the object is in the wrong state.  Such as requesting a solution from an equation solver without initializing it with a coefficient matrix first. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html): *“Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.”*

Comment: Not necessarily, there maybe other processes that can affect a state of a `type` but doesn't require user input. This means that the `type` is necessary for the next flow of statement executions and needs to be of correct state before they are executed. The javadoc clearly states: `Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.`.

Comment: This is not good practice. AssertionErrors should be left to indicate that an `assert` statement failed. If you throw them manually, you risk polluting the program particularly in the situation that someone enables assertions (as both your code and actual `assert`s will throw AssertionErrors). Furthermore, `AssertionError` is a subclass of `Error` and is generally not good to be thrown by a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Oracle guidelines (Programming with assertions)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html), assertions was designed for testing purposes:

> An assertion is a statement in the Java programming language that
>   enables you to test your assumptions about your program. For example,
>   if you write a method that calculates the speed of a particle, you
>   might assert that the calculated speed is less than the speed of
>   light.
>
> Each assertion contains a boolean expression that you believe will be
>   true when the assertion executes. If it is not true, the system will
>   throw an error. By verifying that the boolean expression is indeed
>   true, the assertion confirms your assumptions about the behavior of
>   your program, increasing your confidence that the program is free of
>   errors.

In your example, the developer assumed that the code never reaches the `assert` statement. If, by rare occurrence it does, the `assert(false)` will throw an `Error` (since it should never get there). This was done for testing purposes. So, use assert purely for testing purposes.

Comment: If it's for testing purposes, why does a unit test  @Test
 public void test()
 {
  method();
 }

 private void method()
 {
  assert false : "Crash me";
 } pass?

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ, are you referring to JUnit `assertFalse()` or java specific `assert`? JUnit's `assertFalse` validates that the `condition` is `false` so passing a `false` passes.I am not referring to JUnit or TestNG's `assertFalse` but rather Java's own `assert`.

Comment: I didn't use `assertFalse()` in my code. I used `assert false`only.

Comment: @ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ your example throws an `AssertionError` with the message "Crash me".

Comment: Then there seems to be something wrong with my machine. I'll look into it.

Comment: Enable assert by running your application with a `-ea` argument.