# Java assert(false)

Tags: java

[What is `assert(false)` doing in the following code?](https://github.com/jimmikaelkael/multi-layer-perceptron/blob/master/Mlp.java)

```
public float[] evaluate(float[] inputs)
{
    // propagate the inputs through all neural network
    // and return the outputs
    assert(false);

    float outputs[] = new float[inputs.length];

    for( int i = 0; i < _layers.size(); ++i ) {  
        outputs = _layers.get(i).evaluate(inputs);
        inputs = outputs;
    }

    return outputs;
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480068/assertfalse-vs-runtimeexception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468020/is-assert-false-a-good-practice

Answer (score 1):

The line, as it is, only checks that asserations are not enabled, otherwise throw an `AsserationError`. As you can add an message like

```
assert false: "nope!";
```

there is no equivalent in c#. Also it is in java a keyword but not in c#.