# assert Vs if(var != null) which way is better or is correct?

Tags: java, android

In my app i want to close my cursor in finally statement like this :

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    // some code
} finally {
     cursor.close();
}
```

My IDE highlight `cursor.close();` and tell :

> This method can produce `nullPointerException`

And suggest to way to correct it (im using intelij idea) :
**First:**

```
assert cursor != null;
cursor.close();
```

**Second:**

```
if (cursor != null) {
   cursor.close();
}
```

I want to know what is difference between them and which way is better approach ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/assertion-in-java

Comment: `assert` will crash your app if `cursor` is `null`, either because the assertion itself will trigger an exception, or if it is disabled, you will get a `NullPointerException`. The `if` check will not.

Comment: thank you @CommonsWare , then i must use `if` if i understand correctly :)

Comment: If `Cursor` implements `AutoCloseable` and your Android minSdkLevel is >= 19 (so Java 7 language features are available), this question becomes moot because you should be using try-with-resources instead: `try (Cursor cursor = ...) { // some code }`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java Assertions are only executed if `-ea` (enable assertions) is passed as argument to the JVM. If assertions are enabled and the boolean expression of an assertion evaluates as `false`,an `AssertionError` will be thrown. So assertions are really just useful as debugging feature.

You should definetely use the `if` syntax.

<sub>Note that there also is the syntax `assert booleanFlag : message;` which will pass `message` as message to the `AssertionException` if the booleanFlag is `false`.</sub>

Comment: I would add that (in this case) it is even _semantically wrong_ to use an assert, since it can happen that the cursor is null and that does not have to be the programmer's fault. You don't want to fail fast here, you don't want the program to fail.