# Assertions are not failing in onErrorReturn rx java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, rx-java, vert.x

I am having following code:

```
public Single<Post> doSomething(Post post) {
    String endPoint = "some-url";
    JsonObject payload = new JsonObject().put("message", post.getPost());
    return oAuth.rxApi(HttpMethod.POST, endPoint, payload)
            .map(r -> {
                post.setPostId(r.getString("id"));
                post.setStatus(PostStatus.PROCESSED);
                return post;
            }).onErrorReturn(e -> {
                post.setStatus(PostStatus.FAILED);
                post.setError(e.getMessage());
                return post;
            });
}
```

And I have written following test case for it.

```
@Test
public void shouldHandleFailureWhilePosting() {
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setSocialAccountID("1234");
    post.setAccessToken("ABC");
    post.setPost("Some post to share!!!");

    String shareEndPoint = "some-url";
    JsonObject sharePayload = new JsonObject().put("message", post.getPost());
    when(oAuth2Auth.rxApi(HttpMethod.POST, shareEndPoint, sharePayload)).thenReturn(Single.error(new NoStackTraceThrowable("Error")));

    service.doSomething(post)
            .subscribe(postResponse -> {
                assert postResponse.getError().equals("Errorssss");
                assert postResponse.getAttachedMedia() == null;
                assert postResponse.getPostId() == null;
                assert postResponse.getStatus().equals(PostStatus.FAILED);
            });
}
```

Now my assertions in this case always pass. Even if I make a wrong assertion, it is always green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions are executed in the context of the observable chain, and won't be directly accessible from your tests.

Instead use a `TestSubscriber` to subscribe to the observable chain. It has a number of assertions on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled assertion checks with the `-ea` option?

Assertion, [**by default**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120928/why-is-assert-not-enabled-by-default-in-java), are disabled ... Also, testing framework usually expose own "asserts" methods. For instance, on jUnit (org.junit.Assert), you may find static assertTrue(), assertArrayEquals(), assertNull() and so on

Comment: Yes, `-ea` is enabled. It works for other test cases, but for this it fails.