# JUnit test if Java code assert fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, test-coverage

This seems too easy and obvious, but I cannot find out how to test the following:

**My Java method:**

```
public void doSth(final Foo foo) {
    assert foo != null;
    ..
}
```

**My test:**

```
 @Test
 public void testAssertion() {
      doSth();
      doSth(new Foo());
 }
```

I can test quite many things with `assertEquals` etc., but how to create a test case that gives true if that assert there on `foo != null;` gives negative?

The test I have now goes on green in both cases of assertion, but I cannot catch the assertion fails or not.

I want my code test coverage to 100% and would like to test something meaningful on this line.

Comment: If `doSth();` is part of your production code, it is bad practice to use asserts because they are disabled by default. it should be refactored to use exceptions.

Comment: Did you try with assertNotNull(foo) ?

Comment: The thing is assertion gives now "3/4 branches not covered" if I run the given test, so I would like to know are there any chances to get 4/4. How ever useful that is but for curiosity. I would introduce here term "coverageTesting" and it is what I aim with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you assert that a certain exception is thrown in JUnit 4 tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests)

Comment: The thing is not exactly about asserting exceptions, but testing the assert command is fired or not. Maybe I miss something, but testing that assert is failing is different than test some exception. Although it is not desired thing to happen normally (=highly exceptional) but for my eyes assert and exception are different concepts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`assert` throws an [AssertionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) if the assertion is false.

If you want to test that an assertion occurs when the argument is `null`, you can do it with the `expected` argument of the `@Test` annotation (requires JUnit 4+):

```
@Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
public void testAssertion() {
    doSth(null);
}
```

Comment: This did not affect to coverage percent, but now I at least know how to "test" asserts. Thanks for insights.

Answer (score 2):

Using `assert` in your code is a bad practice.

Try to use Java 8 `Objects.requireNonNull()`

**Java Class**

```
public void doSth(final Foo foo) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(foo);
    ..
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testNPE() {
     doSth(null);
}
```

Comment: It's not good to use `assert` in this particular case, i.e. for argument checking in public methods (see [Oracle guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)), but it's definitively not bad practice in general. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/what-does-the-java-assert-keyword-do-and-when-should-it-be-used) question.