# Why assert(false) give me a green bar when I perform this simple unit test method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

into a JUnit test cla I have this extremelly simple method:

```
public void stupidTest() {
    assert(false);
}
```

The strange thing is that performing this method I obtain a **GREEN BAR** and not a red one as I expected (I think that **assert(true)** have to give me a green bar and **assert(false)** a red bar).

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: to follow @assylias : you can use assert, but by default, they're disabled. Either enable the asserts (not recommended) or use the assert methods provided by your testing framework (here, JUnit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Java assert keyword do, and when should it be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/what-does-the-java-assert-keyword-do-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Hint: if you are just starting with JUnit, there is only **one** assert you want to learn about, and that is **assertThat**. No need to look any assertTrue, ...False, ...Whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert` is a Java keyword: junit doesn't care about it (and it will only be considered by the JVM if you run with the `-ea` option).

If you want to run a junit test, you should use `assertTrue(false);` which is a junit method. That will give you a red bar.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking in `assertTrue` and `assertFalse`. Those one checks if the parameter is true or false when running a JUnit.

Check the [API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

`assert` in java, as you are using it, it's only taken into consideration when compiling with an special option, not when running the test