# Is it possible to put a delay on BufferedReader reading from socket

Tags: java, sockets, delay, bufferedreader

I am wondering is it possible to put a delay on how often a packet is read by the buffered reader when being read from a socket. At the moment there is a server which streams data over local host to a client which reads in the data and splits it. I would like the data not to be read continuously and rather would like to read in a packet every 1/2 second. Below is the code I currently have:

Set up of the BufferedReader:

`

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1240);
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

'

This section of code is where the packets are read in:

```
while (true)    
{

   String line = inFromServer.readLine();

   if (line != null){

      String[] packetData = line.split(",");

      if (packetData.length == 5)
      {
    x = Double.parseDouble(packetData[1]);
        y = Double.parseDouble(packetData[2]);
        z = Double.parseDouble(packetData[3]);
      }
   }
}
```

If anyone could give me help on this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Daniel

Comment: Perhaps put a 0.5 sceond delay into the loop after reading & processing each line, then?

Comment: If `line == null` you must break out of this loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps put a 500 millisecond delay into the loop after reading & processing each line, then? See `Thread.sleep()`.

See:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)
- [How do I fix a compilation error for unhandled exception on call to Thread.sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005549/how-to-properly-use-thread-sleep)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care about packets (low-level networking stuff) or are you just interested in throttling to 1 line per 0.5 seconds. In the latter case just put Thread.sleep(500) in the while loop.