# Want to print text char by char for my textbased game, but it prints out the whole text after the summed delay

Tags: java, text, delay, text-based

Im trying to print out some text char by char with some delay, the problem is that it waits and waits and then prints the whole sentence out. It's like it's printing char by char to a string and then printing that string out once its finished:

```
public static void printWithDelay(String data, TimeUnit unit, long delay) 
  throws InterruptedException {
    for (char ch : data.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(ch);
        unit.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

please help (:

Comment: You may be looking for `System.out.flush();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))?

```
import java.lang.*;

public class PrintWithDelayExample {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        printWithDelay("Hello! World", 500);
    }

    public static void printWithDelay(String data, long delay) {
        for (char c : data.toCharArray()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
                System.out.print(c);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

See [Pausing Execution with sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

And [How to properly use thread sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005549/how-to-properly-use-thread-sleep)

Comment: It will not allow me to do it in under 300 milliseconds and that is way too slow...
Is it really impossible to do it under 300?

Comment: Not for me.
For me if it is under 300 millis, it will just wait lets say 100millis pr. char and then when it is done, it will print it all out in one go... /:

Comment: Is it waiting and then printing all in one go? Did you copy-pasted my code and tested it and saw how it's working? With the current code you posted it's almost impossible to provide more help

Comment: Yeah it's copy pasted, but as i said, then it workes perfectly on 300 millis +, but it doesn't work proberly at under 300 millis

Comment: But what happens under 300 millis? `but it doesn't work proberly at under 300 millis` doesn't provide enough information to see what's not working

Comment: It is as if it is working "behind the scenes", by that i mean, it is waiting for as long as it takes to print the whole text out, but instead of printing every char one at a time, it prints the whole text out when it is "done".

Comment: I may have to just quit it /:

Comment: @DanielWinkel-Pedersen I'll try to make a GIF demonstrating how it works, just I'm waiting for an answer from other user who may help me with which tool he used (as I lost it). Then you could try using it to show me how your problem looks like. Or if you know how, then show me :)

Comment: There isn't really much to show... When i debug and come to the line where im using my method with 10 milliseconds, nothing happens.. no output.. it jumps right past it ..

Comment: 10 millis... maybe your computer is "lagging" while executing program. At 10 millis can your eyes see that? It's too low speed to see how each letter is printed. Try writing a larger text

Comment: That is not the problem, im using 100 chared strings, with 10 methodcalls on 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250 etc. millis, 
And no it is not the lagg...
Maybe it is NetBeans?

Comment: Probably... try compiling and running on terminal (cmd) :) Might help

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: Open CMD (Windows + R -> write `cmd`) then `cd` to the path where your file is (I recommend desktop and place there the file with the code I posted), then write `javac PrintWithDelayExample.java` (it should compile with no errors) after that `java PrintWithDelayExample` and you should see how it works.

Comment: @DanielWinkel-Pedersen then? did it worked? Or wasn't I clear enough somewhere?

Comment: i do as following:
cd C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DungeonGame\src\dungeongame
enter
java main
enter
And it says unable to find or locate main class main

Comment: Please create a new file on your desktop, with the code I provided, then `cd` to your desktop and write `javac PrintWithDelayExample.java` after it compiles write `java PrintWithDelayExample`. So you can see how my example works. The error you're getting is because there's no `main` method on `main` class (Maybe your class has a different name)

Comment: Congratulations! I don't like NetBeans but instead I program on notepad++ and compile on cmd as I showed you. Except for debugging.

Comment: Seriously i am really really thankful for your help, as others have given up helping me (:

Comment: Just make sure to help others in the future as I did. And next time provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a code fragment however it was fine. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by MCVE?
I'm a brand new member at stackoverflow, and will try to help as much as i can (:

Comment: Read the link I provided **M**inimal **C**omplete and **V**erifiable **E**xample is what MCVE stands for.

Answer (score 0):

You may find calling `flush()` will work but there is no guarantee.

```
public static void printWithDelay(String data, TimeUnit unit, long delay)
        throws InterruptedException {
    for (char ch : data.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(ch);
        // Add this.
        System.out.flush();
        unit.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

See [flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, **if any bytes previously written have been buffered** by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes **should immediately be written to their intended destination**.

Comment: @DanielWinkel-Pedersen - Works fine for me. You may have to replace `System.out` with an unbuffered version somehow.That's what the quote means by **is an indication that** - i.e. there is no guarantee it will work.

Comment: @DanielWinkel-Pedersen - see [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+performance+tuning/Chapter+8.+IO+Logging+and+Console+Output/8.1+Replacing+System.out/) for why and how.

Comment: This is waay to technical for my level or programming /:
I just really dont understand why it works for you and not me?

Answer (score 0):

What values are you running this with? If you are using too small of a sleep value, since you are printing everything on one line, it may seem like it is writing all at once.

Try running it with these values to exaggerate the sleep time. You could also try using a `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print` to show you that it is in fact printing one at a time.

```
    try {
        printWithDelay("Some Text", TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks nLee, it works at 300 Milliseconds, but that is too slow..
And it is on 100 Milliseconds, so it shouldn't be instant.. The problem is that if it is under 300 mili, it waits for the whole text to be done, and the prints it out