# I cannot get my printWithDelay method to print faster than 300 milliseconds.

Tags: java, text, delay, thread-sleep, text-based

Here is my method

```
public static void printWithDelay(String data, long delay) {
    for (char c : data.toCharArray()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            System.out.print(c);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

So if i try to run the method with a given String, it will work at 300 milliseconds, but that is a bit too slow. I want it to run kinda like in the old pokemon games where it was printed fairly fast..

If i try to change it to under 300 milliseconds pr char, the output will just stand still until the whole String has been constructed, and then it will print the String..

Please help as this really annoys me /:

Comment: Try invoke `System.out.flush()` after printing a character. You can also do it in one statement: `System.out.append(c).flush();`.

Comment: If that doesn’t help, you likely ran into a limitation you can’t solve. The console, you are printing to, has a limitation on the visual update intervals. In this case, you can’t get better results with printing to stdout. You will have to create your own GUI if you want more control.

Comment: Ahh okay, ill just drop it then 
Thank you for your help (:

Comment: Instead of making new questions from the same issue you would might wanted to **edit** your [Original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019295/want-to-print-text-char-by-char-for-my-textbased-game-but-it-prints-out-the-who).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interval we pass in `Thread.sleep(long millis)` method is in millis, I ran the above code in my `Eclipse` with `Java 8`, character gets printed as per the interval specified, even if I reduce the interval to `10` it printed the character one by one.

What is the interval you tried?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and debug it, it'll get printed char by char.

Comment: Im debugging my whole project now,

Comment: What happens after Thread.sleep(delay)? Did it print the char?

Comment: Its a big project, so it will take a little time

Comment: If i try to debug file with the breakpoint at where it starts. It just debugs for a lof of time, and i cant Step over or anything

Comment: No output or anything it just says: MethodBreakpoint [dungeongame.Main].printWithDelay '(Ljava/lang/String;J)V' successfully submitted.

Comment: Nothing happens when i debug the printWithDelay method

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your loop inside the try { }.

```
    try {
        for (char c : data.toCharArray()){
             Thread.sleep(delay);
             System.out.print(c);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
```

Comment: No matter what i try, it does not work at under 300, i have tried everything from 10 - 299
As said it works perfectly fine at 300,.. no problems