# When would this catch block be reached?

Tags: java, exception

I've used `Thread.sleep` for all kinds of different reasons, but one thing I've never understood is when an exception would occur during this try /catch block:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 second.
} catch (Exception x) {
    fail("Failed due to an exception during Thread.sleep!");
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

What would have to occur within the computer to actually hit an exception on `Thread.sleep`? My best guess, would be that maybe the system clock has a once in a lifetime "skip of a beat" like a heartbeat, but how often does this happen..

So in essence, my question is:  When executing `Thread.sleep`, what would have to occur internally for `#sleep` to throw an exception?

Comment: The only checked exception i'm aware of is `InterruptedException`.  (Note, if the code were catching something more specific than `Exception`, you probably wouldn't be scratching your head here.  You should never `catch (Exception)`, for a number of reasons including that.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look in the JavaDoc for [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) you see exactly what might happen:

*Throws:

IllegalArgumentException - if the value of millis is negative

InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted   status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.*

An example on how to interrupt another thread might look like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread sleepThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted!");
                }
            }
        });
        sleepThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        sleepThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

This will print

> Interrupted!

Comment: so - what.. using something like `wait()` on the method?

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for that.  Will accept in 3 minutes ;) this code here gave me a practical (yet unpractical) example of how to use this, and when it would hit that exception.

Comment: also, i hadn't had much experience with threading in general, so the doc didn't _particularly_ help

Comment: @sircapsalot: No, it might not be the clearest Javadoc. Glad the example helped clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The `Thread` class defines an [interrupt method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29). When it's called (obviously from another thread) by a thread and there's no security exception, an `InterruptedException` is thrown.

The purpose is, precisely (and normally), to interrupt the sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep(someValue) can fire InterruptedException.
More info about handling this exception and reson for this you can find [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).

You can find a lot usefull answers on SO. Here is the one for example:
[When does Java's Thread.sleep throw InterruptedException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087475/when-does-javas-thread-sleep-throw-interruptedexception)

Answer (score 0):

When a thread interrupt is issued, for example if a signal was sent to shut the JVM down.

Comment: The usual reason for a thread being interrupted would be another thread calling the [`interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) method on it.

Comment: Agreed, perhaps a poor example (although a real one).  I actually up-voted Keppil's answer :D

Answer (score 0):

The Thread can throw an `InterruptedException` (which you should use instead of general Exception) when the Thread is interrupted (usually by the interrupt() method called from another Thread) instead of just waiting. It has nothing to do with the sleep() method.