# Java thread Interrupted Exception

Tags: java, exception, static

Here Is my program that produces an `InterruptedException`.

***timepass.java***

```
 public class timePass {
    private static void book() {
        System.out.print("book");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
            Thread.sleep(1);
            book();
      }
    }
```

I would like to know the reason for the thrown exception.

Comment: Where is the exceptionel thrown? Im guessing its at the Thread call?

Comment: Please paste the Exception into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put code in try catch block

```
 try
  {
  Thread.sleep(1);
  book();
  } 
  catch(InterruptedException e)
  {
   System.out.println("Error message");
  }
```

Comment: Yes , I understand this can be a solution for my problem. But I would like to know the reason why this exception is being thrown.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087475/when-does-javas-thread-sleep-throw-interruptedexception

Answer (score 1):

It's because Thread.sleep could probably throw an Exception so you just have to catch it or give it to a higher level.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1);
    book();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use **thread sleep** you need to try catch a  (`InterruptedException` e)